# How to increase screenshot quality in the appium webdriver for IOS?

Tags: python, selenium, appium

im using element.screenshot_as_png()
On iOS quality is so bad:
[image]

Do screenshot manually has better quality:

[image]

On Android this element screenshoted pretty good by this command:
[image]

I tried many ways, including other screenshot formats, base64 decoding, etc.

If anyone can help please tell me

Comment: looks like heavy compression... maybe try as BMP.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that would help for Python automation with that specific method but you can try adding `{"screenshotQuality": 0}` to your driver capabilities. Note that setting to the highest quality(0) can lead to OOM crashes when doing the screenshot.